# how to show alert when user enter other then number value in textfield

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I have iphone app in which i enter any number value like 10 2 0 1 0.2 etc i want that instead of this if user enter any text it should alert that enter a number.

```
    UIAlertView * alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Value Must Be In Number " delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    if (textField==txtMobileNo) 
    {
        [self validatePhone];
    }else
    {
        [textField resignFirstResponder];

    }
    // called when 'return' key pressed. return NO to ignore.
    return YES;
}

- (BOOL) validatePhone
{
    NSString *phoneRegex = @"^+(?:[0-9] ?){6,14}[0-9]$"; 
    NSPredicate *phoneTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", phoneRegex]; 
    if ([phoneTest evaluateWithObject:txtMobileNo.text] == YES) 
    {
        NSLog(@"proper phone nO ");        
        return YES;   
    }
    else
    {
        UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil message:@"Please,Enter Your Person proper phone no" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss" otherButtonTitles:nil  ];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];
        NSLog(@"phone no. not in proper format");
        return NO;
        [txtMobileNo becomeFirstResponder];

    }  
}
```

I hope you helpful.

Comment: I only want to enter a one digit only if i entet in your code abc it shows error but when i enter 5 then it also shows error why

Comment: you enter any 0 -9 digit only ,but enter another character then it gives the alert message to you.

Comment: i tried only your code but when clean build it worked fine thanks and one thing i have posted another graph can you see that if you can help me out here is link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10577715/how-to-create-a-histograph-in-iphone-app-inside-view

Answer (score 0):

That disrupts the app kind of, doesn't it? What you want to look at is the UITextfield delegate methods. Set your viewController as the textields delegate and make it respond o UITextFieldDelegate protocol.

I would implement the textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString method and check the replacementString for unwanted characters.

But rather than displaying an alert, I guess I would just return NO if unwanted characters are contained there. Then, when the user enters something other than what you want, nothing happens.

Comment: I mean if you are entering ABC  instead off  1 2 10 then it may show user that enter number value only how will user know if he enters wrong value that i must enter any number

Comment: Yu _could_ raise an alert. Just think it breaks the flow if you type and an alert comes up. label the textfield so that it is clear that only numbers are needed in the first place, or make a uilabel appear that tells the user to only enter numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You validate the entered character and do your logic in this delegate ,

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string{

// your logic to restriction goes here.like check the entered char and through alert
}




-(BOOL) validateNumericValue:(NSString*) textValue
{   
    NSNumberFormatter* numberFormatter = [[[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
    NSNumber* number = [numberFormatter numberFromString:textValue];

    if (number != nil) 
    {
        return YES;
    }
    return NO;
}
```

Comment: I know this validation goes here how to perform that logic of validation my question is that

Answer (score 0):

you can check if it is a number using the following:-

```
NSString *yourString= @"121212";
NSCharacterSet *decimalNUmSet= [NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet];
BOOL isNum= ([[yourString stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:decimalNUmSet] isEqualToString:@""] || 
                      [[yourString stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:decimalNUmSet] isEqualToString:@"."]);
```

here the second part includes decimal numbers also.

the other way is to present a numeric keyboard to user so that he can type only numbers.