# How to alert when user enters nothing?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm making a JavaScript project and I want to alert when the user enters nothing in the prompt

```js
function verifyage() {
var age = prompt("enter your age:", "");
var status = (age >= 18) ? "adult" : "minor";
if(status == "minor") {
alert("you are too young");
} else if (status == "adult") {
alert("you're in");
} else if (status == "null") {
alert("you need to enter your age");
}
else {
void(0);
}}
```

```html
<button onclick="verifyage();" type="button">watch movie</button>
```

What it's supposed to do:

- define a variable age which defines the age of user
- define a variable status which has two value adult and minor
- prompt for the age of the user
- alert the message you are too young when the user enter a number less than 18
- alert the message you're in when user enters number greater than 18
- alert the message you have to enter your age when user enters nothing

But when I test it and enter nothing it says you are too young - why?

I tried [how to show alert when user enter other then number value in textfield](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10577549/how-to-show-alert-when-user-enter-other-then-number-value-in-textfield) and other but nothing.
**EDIT**:When i press cancel it says you are too young...help?

Comment: hint: use a switch statement!

Comment: `it says you are too young why?`   Because an empty string (`""`)  is less than `18`

Comment: its because you are using an If Else statement so if its over 18 it will be true but everything else will be false!!

Comment: @adddff, have a look at my solution to handle numbers/string/undefined as input :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function verifyage() {
  var age = prompt("enter your age:", "");
  if(isNaN(parseFloat(age))) {          // check: if user entered a number/string/blank
    alert("You entered nothing");
  }
  else {
    var status = (age >= 18) ? "adult" : "minor";
      if(status == "minor") {
        alert("you are too young");
      } else if (status == "adult") {
        alert("you're in");
      } 
  }
}
verifyage();
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that you want to continue to prompt the user to enter something into the field.  To accomplish that I would have a while loop that checks to make sure the age is not blank.  It also looks unnecessary to set status to then just check for the value when you could just check the age.

```
function verifyage() {
        var age = prompt("enter your age:", "");
        //var status = (age >= 18) ? "adult" : "minor";
        while(age === "" || isNaN(age)){
            age = prompt("enter your age:", "");
        }   
        if(age <= 18) {
            alert("you are too young");
        } else if (age > 18) {
            alert("you're in");
        } 
        else {
            void(0);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function verifyage() {
var age = prompt("enter your age:", "");
if(age=='' || age<="0" || isNaN(age)){alert ("you have to enter your age");
}
var status = (age >= 18) ? "adult" : "minor";
if(status == "minor") {
alert("you are too young");
} else if (status == "adult") {
alert("you're in");
} else if (status == "null") {
alert("you need to enter your age");
}
else {
void(0);
}}
```

First of all if you don't select the age it will assign it to 0 which is under 18 the first if will obtain so to avoid that add if statement to validate if the user don't write anything or write 0 by error like the code above

Comment: You have missing quotes, 0 indentation, and 0 explanation. Not a good way to teach people what is wrong in their code.

Comment: Thank you , I tried to edit my answer to be better and more useful

Answer (score 0):

I am no javascript expert, but looking at your code I think "null" will not do what you want it to. Right now it is explicitly looking for the typed text "null". In c++ for example you could use

```
else if (status == "")
```

or (maybe even better) just use else (so that everything except for adult/minor could give an error)

Also I would not make the comparison with the variable "status", but with "age". This should be the first comparison you make. When the typed age == "" ( <- nothing) then you could give an alert, prompting the user to type their age again.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Please see the below correction, You were running into trouble since when you do enter, the value of your age variable was 0.

```js
function verifyage() {
var age = prompt("enter your age:", "");
var status = (age >= 18) ? "adult" : "minor";
if (age == 0)
 status = "null";
if(status == "minor") {
alert("you are too young");
} else if (status == "adult") {
alert("you're in");
} else if (status == "null") {
alert("you need to enter your age");
}
else {
void(0);
}}
```

```html
<button onclick="verifyage();" type="button">watch movie</button>
```